# How to recalculate correct position

Tags: jquery

I think I am been misunderstood here so I will rephrase my question.

THE PROBLEM: when I **"hover"** over the menu the black span with class **"problem"** follows my mouse but it messes up its position because I don't know to calculate it correctly:( 
***Try to hover over my menu to see the problem.***
Been trying for two days to figure this out, but no success...

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/w3DrE/)

Here's the [LINK](http://www.snagomuma.com/newlife/) of my site.

Any help or suggestion?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu ul li').hover(function(){
        var index=$(this).index();
        var width=$(this).outerWidth();        
        $('.problem').stop().animate({'marginLeft':135*index+195,'width':width},1000);     
    });
});
```

Comment: jsbin or jsfiddle, with just the code that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by updating the `.menu` styles thusly:

```
float: none;
width: 715px;
height: 30px;
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: 9px auto;
```

You'll then need to move the active element behind it, which you can possibly do by applying a negative `top-margin`

Comment: So then relative positioning and negative top value?

Answer (score 1):

Set the CSS of the menu div to:

```
width://insert wanted width here
margin:auto;
```

With a fixed width and auto margin, CSS will center your div.