# How to animate span to correct position?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recalculate correct position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643303/how-to-recalculate-correct-position)

I have been trying to achive this effect: When I hover over menu , span with class **"problem"** follows my mouse and it's expandig dynamicly (has the same width as hovered li tag). The width of my span is working OK but its position is messed up because I don't know
how to make proper calculations. 
***Try to hover over my menu to see the problem.***

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/w3DrE/) 
Does anybody knows how to solve this problem or point me in the right direction?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu ul li').hover(function(){
        var index=$(this).index();
        var width=$(this).outerWidth();        
        $('.problem').stop().animate({'marginLeft':135*index+195,'width':width},1000);     
    });
});
```

Comment: Can anybody give me a hint or a suggestion?

Comment: `var left=$(this).offset().left;` then set `'marginLeft':left, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work better I think:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3DrE/16/

Comment: I love you!!!(not that i am gay) It was THE ANSWER!!! THANK YOU,YOU SAVED ME!!

Answer (score 4):

Urm, You didnt get your floats and the underlying text properly. Your `li` appear to be floated left but it exceeds its parent's width. Hence the last menu item(`li`) comes down automatically. You must either reduce the font-size or do something like this.

```
ul li{
    float:left;
    width : 120px;
    overflow : hidden;
    white-space : nowrap;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w3DrE/13/).